Can 持っていく be used with a group of people?
I had read this post:
Using 持っていく with people
But recently I am reading a manga, there is a bubble of text says 食堂に入って 大丈夫なら 持っていくけど? which is heavily like "bringing a group of people to cafeteria". Based on the context, translated it into bringing anything else doesn't seem correct, because all other bubbles of speech are all talking about people in a group.
I had a look on nihongomaster and saw an example. It said
監督はチームをトーナメント優勝に今一歩という所までもっていったのに悔しいことだった。
It was annoying, as the manager took his team to a near-miss in the tournament.
Is this example correct? Does Japanese use 持っていく with a group of people?
Thank you.

Edit (added context)
Summary:

Main character is Myne (マイン), a workshop owner although she is very young.
She becomes a newly head of an orphanage.
The orphanage is in the verge of collapse. Ran out of money, adult orphans - people are working, find it just enough to live. The children are starving to death.
After acquire the orphanage, Myne is going to reform it, by using her own money and attendants. Then setup a branch of her workshop there, so the orphans can make money to feed the entire of the orphanage.
The current story started at the point: Myne had her attendants and orphans to do a total cleaning of the orphanage.
Myne divided people into groups to do various tasks of cleaning.








Welcome to the Japanese SE. Can you please post more details about the context in the manga you are reading?

@Gui Imamura
Hello. I have updated the context. Sorry the post become very long now. I had tried my best to shorten it.

Haha it was indeed a difficult story to post the context for. Tbh I would've looked into it if you had said it was from the Honzuki no Gekokujō. I'm looking a bit more into the context right now.

Cool! You are a fan of the manga too? And, if my given context is not enough, I am sorry for it. For further details, it is from Chapter 10, Part 2 of manga Honzuki no Gekokujō

I've only watched the anime, will spare some time to read the manga too.

Aside from an evil human trafficker who treats people completely as objects, it is almost impossible for someone to say 持ってくる when referring to taking people to a room. So it is reasonable to assume that this boy is trying to bring something other than a person into the dining room. (Note that, while a チーム might be a group of people, it is not people themselves. For example, you can say チームがある.)
I don't know this work well, but the character who said this line seems to be ルッツ, and in the same scene of the original novel, he was making a food called カルフェバター in the basement of the boys' dorm.

ルッツはこれからマイン工房の作業場になる男子棟の地階の掃除の監視とマイン工房から道具の搬入をする。そして、その場でカルフェバターを作るのだ。

So also in this manga version, it's probably the freshly made カルフェバター that he is trying to bring into the dining room, though this is not explicitly mentioned on the pages you provided. The subsequent pages may have some clue about what he was doing.

Hello. I'd read the Web Novel version as well, and thought that may be Lutz (ルッツ) tried to bring something to the dinning hall. But in the manga, it seems the artist (mangaka) had excluded the detail of Lutz making food. The subsequent pages describe the scene of the dinning hall, people all gather together there, Myne (the orphanage's head)'s greeting as the new head, and people eating together.

@KhangDinhHoang Then your confusion is understandable, but the first part of my answer still holds true. Whatever it is, it's safe to assume Lutz is trying to bring something other than people into the hall.

if "チーム" (Team) is a group of people but not people itself, would "孤児" (Orphans) also?

@KhangDinhHoang Orphans are people. You have to say 孤児を連れて行く regardless of whether it's one orphan or many orphans. Orphans are counted using 人, while チーム is counted using つ or 個.

I've read the whole chapter (didn't have to read the previous chapters as I know the story from the anime), but it does seem like Gil is referring to the orphans. It could also be "作業を持ってくる", or it could refer to the 掃除 etc, but it is more likely because Gil doesn't have very good manners when choosing words to speak. I don't think it was because Gil spoke of the orphans in a depreciatory or contemptuous way.
I've also found the chapter in English, where the translation points to the orphans as well:


We can get moving once the dining hall's open for us.

